# achartengine and hide series in legend

Tags: android, achartengine

This is possible to hide series(title and line) in legend chart, lise on chart is still visible? I wnat only hide data in legend my I want to see my series on chart. I don;t want to hide all series in legend, only few.

Comment: can u post images & code to explain what u have so far done

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can hide some of the legend items this way:

```
seriesRenderer.setShowLegendItem(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
```