# Hide series in legend in XYSeriesRenderer, AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I saw from here: [achartengine and hide series in legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001676/achartengine-and-hide-series-in-legend), that you can use

`seriesRenderer.setShowLegendItem(false);`

and it should hide a specific series. However, I can't find this in `XYSeriesRenderer`. I'm using achartengine-1.1.0-rc2.jar library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a nightly build version including this feature [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).